# Is it possible to get the number of loop iterations from inside a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, max

Suppose I have a `for` loop that looks something like this:

```
for ii = 1:randi(100) 
  a = ???;  
  myFunc(ii/a); 
end
```

Is it possible to find out what the maximum value of `ii` is going to be inside of the loop? ie, is there some function/package/method that would allow me to set `a` to that value?

Comment: There is no statement or syntactic element for that. However, in the `for` line you necessarily know that value. So you can simply assign it to a variable first: `a = randi(100); for ii = 1:a ...`

Comment: It really wouldn't make sense to have a special function or syntax to get that number since `for` loop already requires you to spell out the values you are looping over, and by spelling it out, you already have the *max* number of iterations. In your case,  the max number is `randi(100)` and so simply assign `a=randi(100)` before the loop as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

No, you would need to specify the loop values up front, at which point it's trivial.

Either work out `a` from a predetermined array of loop values:

```
loopVals = 1:randi(100);
a = loopVals(end); % assumes loopVals is increasing, could use max(loopVals) if not
for ii = loopVars
    myfunc( ii/a );
end
```

Or you can start by defining `a`:

```
a = randi(100);
for ii = 1:a
    myfunc( ii/a );
end
```